# Load external javascript file inside HTML file from android assets folder into WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm trying to load an external JavaScript file into an HTML file. Both are placed in the assets folder.

This is my `htmlTest.html` file:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        func();


    </script>

</body>
```

And this is my test.js file:

```
function func(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#EDIFICI').children().click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });

    });
}
```

Both files are located in the root of the assets folder.
I load htmlTest.html into my WebView like this:

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmlTest.html");
```

If I put JavaScript code inline directly inside the HTML page it works, but it doesn't when I link an external JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in my javascript file. It works like I stated in my example. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

1.on `onCreate` add `getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`

2.change .js like this

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
 <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/xxxxx.js"></script>
</head>
```

And xxxxx.js is in the assets folder.

In the code

```
WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
        oWebView.clearCache(true);
        oWebView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        oWebView.setInitialScale(1);
        oWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        oWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        oWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        oWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        oWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        oWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        oWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        oWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
webView.evaluateJavascript(yourFileAsString)
```

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: Variable yourFileAsString contains valid javascript or you pass file path?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your script as follow

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
```

And add test.js file to folder with html